# Where do I find a list of all X keysyms these days?

Tags: xorg, keyboard

They used to be in /usr/lib/X11/XKeysymDB or /usr/share/X11/XKeysymDB, but those have been missing from Ubuntu for a while. I've tried google, but all I get are more references to XKeysymDB or the outputs of different people's `xmodmap -pke`. Where is the concise list?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably the best up-to-date values for key symbol definitions is to look at the source-code.

Basically its just a list of keysym names  with their associated codes.

```
sudo apt-get install x11proto-core-dev
```

Two key keyfiles in `/usr/include/X11`:

The main definition file:

```
/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
```

Vendor specific (i.e. Debian/Ubuntu):

```
/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h
```

There are a number of other header files in the same folder you can also examine:

```
$ grep -l '#define.*XK_' /usr/include/X11/*.h
```

Example definition from `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`:

```
#define XK_BackSpace                     0xff08  /* Back space, back char */
#define XK_Tab                           0xff09
#define XK_Linefeed                      0xff0a  /* Linefeed, LF */
#define XK_Clear                         0xff0b
#define XK_Return                        0xff0d  /* Return, enter */
#define XK_Pause                         0xff13  /* Pause, hold */
#define XK_Scroll_Lock                   0xff14
#define XK_Sys_Req                       0xff15
#define XK_Escape                        0xff1b
#define XK_Delete                        0xffff  /* Delete, rubout */
```

Comment: Cheers, but I can't see XF86Bluetooth or XF86WLAN etc, so is there another header too?

Comment: ... updated - bluetooth/wlan is in XF86...

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Oops though, I didn't mean to vote that as a 'great comment'.

Comment: For occasional Googlers: equivalent package for Fedora/Red Hat is called xorg-x11-proto-devel

Comment: Update: these days, the interesting files in Fedora now live in libxkbcommon-devel

Comment: The package is x11proto-dev in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you want to learn the code for a specific key on your keyboard, you can use `xev` for X11 or `wev` for Wayland.

After starting `xev`/`wev`, you can press the key and see the X events printed to the terminal.

You can use `xev | grep keysym`/`wev | grep keysym` to filter the lines for the essential information. The keysym you need will be the second second argument in parenthesis.

Comment: Not that `xev` is for X11. The corresponding software for Wayland is `wev`.

Comment: @robertspierre Thanks for the comment and for the edit! (Approved.)